# How to unload pg_table_def table to s3

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'd like to take a dump of schema of redshift and do some comparisons among different environments.

```
unload('select * from pg_table_def') 
to 's3://blah/blah/stage.txt' 
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=XXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXX' 
parallel off allowoverwrite manifest;
```

But the code above throws me the following error.

```
INFO:  Function "format_type(oid,integer)" not supported.
INFO:  Function "pg_table_is_visible(oid)" not supported.
ERROR:  Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.
```

Any idea how to make this work ? or is there any way other way to get the schema. i need to know sort key and dist key information as well.

Comment: I thought about trying to copy the relevant `pg_table_def` rows to a temp table, and unloading that, but I can't figure out how to copy that leader node table into a temp table either!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redshift keeps certain information in special area on the leader node whereas  `UNLOAD` commands are processed on each slice (AFAIK) and therefore can't use leader node only functions.

You would probably need to extract this from an external machine using `psql`.